# How to write conditional "assertThat" using assertj.core.api.Assertions?

Tags: java-8, integration-testing, assertj

Hey guys I have the following code:

```
# number 1, 2, 3 are all "long" type
Assertions.assertThat(number1).isGreaterThan(number2),
Assertions.assertThat(number3).isLessThan(number4)
```

And I want to achieve something like:

```
if Assertions.assertThat(number1).isGreaterThan(number2) success, 
then skip:
   Assertions.assertThat(number3).isLessThan(number4)
else evaluate:
   Assertions.assertThat(number3).isLessThan(number4)
```

How can I write the code for this idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This not possible with AssertJ.

Why not simply using if else?

```java
if (number1 > number2) 
  assertThat(number3).isLessThan(number4);
else 
  assertThat(number3).isLessThan(number5);
```

Comment: Ah yes, you're correct. I should think out of the box. But I am also curious if there's an "assert-style" way to realize my intention.

Comment: There is no elegant solution for this in AssertJ, we don't think adding such capability as the regular if-else constructs in java is still a better approach IMO.